# Нужна ли запятая в обороте "не иначе(,) как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется предложение (пишу приблизительный текст, поэтому к смыслу не придирайтесь): "На него занятия спортом подействуют не иначе(,) как самым положительным образом". Так вот, я вечно путаюсь в запятых в подобных оборотах. Я запятую поставил, но сомневаюсь. Нужна ли тут запятая перед "как", а если не нужна, то почему (какое на этот счет существует правило)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: "На него занятия спортом подействуют не иначе как самым положительным образом".

ПРАВИЛО

1. НЕ ИНАЧЕ КАК. Это частица со значением только, лишь, исключительно, наверняка, скорее всего: "Местом производства стало местечко Флинт, названное так не иначе как в честь знаменитого пиратского капитана".
2. НЕ ИНАЧЕ, КАК (с логическим ударением): Это делается не инАче, как в законном порядке, на бумаге.В данном случае оборот относится к однородным членам, с чем и связано изменение в  интонации.
3. НЕ ИНАЧЕ, КАК ТОЛЬКО "Шлюпка могла пойти куда-нибудь не иначе, как только с разрешения самого Рожественского".