# Иначе(,) чем "...." не назовешь

Tags: пунктуация

Иначе, чем школы высшего пилотажа узаконенного социального бандитизма, их не назовешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь прежде всего нужны кавычки для "школы высшего пилотажа узаконенного социального бандитизма".

Во-вторых, обычная форма этого оборота: *"(не) иначе, **как**"*. В вашем примере "как" тоже смотрелось бы много лучше. Если же переносить на "иначе чем" пунктуационные правила, относящиеся к "иначе(,) как", то в принципе могут быть варианты и с обособлением и без. Зависит от степени распространенности оборота, интонации (акцента) - и вообще от воли автора.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_470
[Нужна ли запятая в обороте "не иначе(,) как"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34762)

В Вашем случае я не вижу причин акцентировать на "как" (сравните с примером на "Грамоте"), поэтому рекомендовал бы не обособлять.

***Иначе как "школы высшего пилотажа узаконенного социального бандитизма" их не назовешь***.

Хотя, признаться, такое длинное "название" тоже не нравится в данном сочетании. Не верю я, что нельзя короче сказать, а, значит, и утверждение автора, что "иначе не назовешь" становится весьма сомнительным.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Мне тоже кажется, что запятые не нужны.

Comment: *Во-вторых, обычная форма этого оборота: "(не) иначе, **чем**".* Наверно, тут уже о "как" речь, опечатка? Кстати, с НЕ (не иначе как) действительно тоже можно сказать? Не могу представить такого... "Не иначе как первый снег", например, — это не то. Здесь нет продолжения.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - Спасибо. пусть будет опечатка. Хотя вернее всего считать её следствием небрежного редактирования. Помнится, я очень долго рожал эту фразу - ну и перемудрил, вестимо. Исправил, короче.

Comment: *Помнится, я очень долго рожал єту фразу - ну и перемудрил, вестимо.* :))) А про "с НЕ" можете что-то сказать?

Comment: Про "не" - несколько удивелен вопросом. А почему нельзя-то? ***"Назвал бы депутата N не иначе как свиньей, но парламентские нормы не позволяют мне этого сделать"*** (Фраза в оригинале принадлежит Никите Богословскому, имела конкретного адресата и звучала немного по-другому, но суть, надеюсь, понятна).

Comment: Точно, по вашей ссылке на Грамоте об этом и говорится! Просто я в первую очередь рассматривал пример Алёнки (составив подобную фразу в своём свежем вопросе). В них конструкция: [Иначе чем чем-то что-то не /глагол/]. "Иначе" начинает предложение или стоит как пояснение, например, после двоеточия. Вы уверены, что и в таких случаях обособлять не надо? Мне кажется, что тоже не надо, но нету полной уверенности, что это тот же случай.

Answer (score 1):

В Интернете есть интересный образец, причем без обособления: **Иначе чем провокационным** я назвать это выступление не могу. Сравнить: Это выступление **не иначе как** провокационное.

Тогда можно остановиться на таком упрощенном варианте: **Иначе чем** школами  узаконенного социального бандитизма их не назовешь.

Еще пример: Его во Франции ещё при жизни иначе как кровавым чудовищем не называли.